# How can I use Visual Studio Team Services to build/compile a project that has dependent APIs/Libraries

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, azure-devops, sdl

I am trying to learn to use Visual Studio Team Services. I have a simple Hello World type application that has dependencies written by someone else. Specifically, I am using SDL2 to display a window for a few seconds. I can build it locally just fine, but when I build it online using the VSTS online build process, it complains that it can't find any of the SDL dependencies such as "SDL.h".

This is the sample code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = nullptr;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        std::cout << "SDL could not initialize. SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (window == nullptr)
            std::cout << "Window could not be created. SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError();
        else
        {
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
            SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, nullptr, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            SDL_Delay(2000);
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = nullptr;
    screenSurface = nullptr;
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

What steps do I need to follow in order to build something online that requires pre-built external dependencies?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community as my IDE and, of course, the Visual Studio website for code repositories/building.

I hope I gave enough specifics.

Comment: How did you reference SDL dependencies? When you use TFS build, the source that you reference requires the same location as your local.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is something solved by Package Management. The idea is that you have a package feed where external dependencies are versioned and stored, and you can retrieve them at build time.

Unfortunately, VSTS package management feeds only support NPM, Maven, and NuGet packages. The C++ ecosystem doesn't really have a de facto package management tool; the closest I can find is Conan. SDL2 appears to be something that is typically pre-installed system-wide (on Linux, via `yum` or `apt`).

Here are some possibilities:

- (Assuming Git for version control) Store your external dependency in a Git submodule backed by Git-LFS, and reference the dependency via relative path.
- (Assuming TFVC for version control) Store your external dependency in the TFVC repo and reference the dependency via relative path
- Use a private build agent and pre-install the dependency
- Investigate Conan as a package manager for SDL2 -- this looks promising, but I don't have time to dig into it right now